# How to automatically put a space after the first parenthesis in f(x) g(y)?

Tags: spacing

When I write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{\lparen}{\rparen}

\begin{document}
    \[
        w = \int f\p*{x} g\p*{\frac{y}{2}} h\p*{z}\ dx
    \]
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

but the three functions are squeezed too close to each other.
In fact, it's so bad that it looks like `g` is attached to `f(x)` rather than to `(y/2)`.

So I need to add some space after the `)`. Clearly it's easy to fix via `\,` as follows:

```
        w = \int f\p*{x}\,g\p*{\frac{y}{2}}\,h\p*{z}\ dx
```

[image]

but I obviously don't want to litter the code with `\,` everywhere!

Is there a way to make the space after a closing right parenthesis do this automatically?
(Note, this shouldn't affect behaviors in other situations -- so, for example, the spacing after a closing parenthesis should stay the same as it is originally if it is followed by a `+` sign instead of another function.)

Comment: Not automatically, as a space there is generally not desired.

Comment: @egreg: How do people normally solve this problem then?

Comment: @Mehrdad by using the spacing commands as you have in your fixed example.

Comment: You can add one or more `\,` thin spaces to achieve a spaced result

Comment: @PaulGessler: Is it normal to put spaces between every single product manually though? I feel like there's gotta be a better way I don't know.

Comment: The other way is to use the first form, it isn't clear to me the spacing is an improvement here.

Comment: @Mehrdad The problem is usually solved by not adding a thin space.

Comment: `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{\lparen}{\rparen\,}` will automatically add space, and you can replace your `\ ` with another `\,` at the end if needed.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Did you read the last sentence in the question?

Comment: Technically, yes. But I certainly didn't retain its meaning between when I was reading and when I was commenting. My mistake.

Comment: @egreg: I should note that making an alternative to `\p` isn't out of the question, as long as it can differentiate between the different use cases. I don't know enough LaTeX to figure it out, but I feel like there ought to be some combination of `\mathord`, `\mathbin`, `\mathclose`, etc. that achieves this in a better manner (because if my understanding is correct, those can differentiate between the different contexts), except I don't know what it could be...

Comment: @Mehrdad the spacing between the classes (here mathclose (or mathinner) and mathord is fixed, so if you want to change the spacing using `\,` is by far the most robust way but as egreg and I comment above, _not_ changing the spacing is the standard preferred markup here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see, so it's normal for the `g` to look more attached to the `f(x)` than its own arguments?

Comment: It only looks that way if you read it that way: It's an implied product and so the spacing should normally be the same as other implied products eg `abc` which are also set tight. Also it would be more usual to use `\,` rather than `\ ` before the `dx` to get tighter spacing there as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\mathinner` adds a space before a following math ord atom, but the usual space is set before a binary or relational operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{\lparen}{%
  \rparen
  % the math atom before is expected to be a `\mathclose`,
  % then we need to cancel the space between `\mathclsoe`
  % and `\mathinner` that is added in non-script styles.
  \@ifnextchar{,}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{;}{}{%
  \@ifnextchar{\colon}{}{%
    \nonscript\!%
    \mathinner{}%
  }}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    % automatic space setting:
    \[
        w\p*{y} = \int f\p*{x} g\p*{\frac{y}{2}} + h\p*{z}, i\p*{z} dx
    \]
    % manual space setting:
    \[
        w(y) = \int f(x)\,g\mleft(\frac y2\mright) + h(z), i(z)\,dx
    \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\mathinner` does not add spaces in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` (except before a math operator/`\mathop`). This might be a limitation or a feature (more compact subscripts).
- Support for punctuation chars `,`, `;`, `\colon` added, if they are directly following. If they are hidden inside macros, then they are not detected.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like this messes up the spacing when there's a comma after the closing parenthesis. Do you happen to know how to fix it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Except for `\mathclose` there is always a space in non-script math styles. This can be compensated by `\!` manually or the definition must explicit check for punctuation characters.